# dynamic values in the table to be inserted in an array using php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

```
<table>
    <thead>  
    <tr>
    <th>Agent Name</th>
    <th>Total Indent</th>
    <!--company name column header starts here-->
    <?php 
      $todaysdate= date('Y-m-d');
      $strSQL1 = "SELECT DISTINCT companyname FROM pamphletsbooking_tbl WHERE bookingdate='$todaysdate' AND pointname= '$pointname1' ORDER BY companyname ASC";
      $query1 = mysqli_query($db, $strSQL1);
      while ($result1 = mysqli_fetch_array($query1)){    
      $companyname1=$result1['companyname'];            
      echo "<th>";
      echo $companyname1;  
      echo "</th>";
      }     
    ?>
    <!--company name column header ends here-->    
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php
    $strSQL ="SELECT * FROM paperagents_tbl WHERE pointshortname= '$pointname1' ORDER BY agentname ASC";
    $query = mysqli_query($db, $strSQL);
    $i=0; 
    $v="vendor";

     while($result = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) 
    {
      $a=$result["agentname"]."";
      $b=$result["Totalindent"]."";
      ?>
        <tr>
          <td><?=$a?></td> 
          <td><?=$b?></td>
          <?php 
            $todaysdate= date('Y-m-d');
            $strSQL1 = "SELECT DISTINCT companyname FROM pamphletsbooking_tbl WHERE bookingdate='$todaysdate' AND pointname= '$pointname1' ORDER BY companyname ASC";
            $query1 = mysqli_query($db, $strSQL1);
            while ($result1 = mysqli_fetch_array($query1)){    
          ?>
          <td><input type="number" tabindex="1" value="" name="<?=$v.$i?>"></td>[out put of this code][1]
          <?php   
            }     
          ?>
          </tr>         
          <?php
            $i++;
    }
    ?>
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

[using this output i need to insert the data from the textbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8478I.jpg)
 - Here Agent Name  and company name like google yahoo is fetched dynamically from database.
 - Under google there is only one textbox which is looped every where.
 - Here the problem is there is a need of inserting data accordingly like agent from textbox to database.
 - At last every time the agent and company changes according to the pointname in the query given.

Comment: could you please show the wire frame of your expected result

Comment: I don't exactly understand whats you problem or what you want, please explain it again. But as far, here an advise: There is no need to do `$a=$result["agentname"]."";` and then `echo $a` ... why you don't simply `echo $result["agentname"];` ? It would be much more easy to read. Second point: Where does `$pointname1` come from?

Comment: echo $a is easier instead of echo $result["agentname"]   AND $pointname1 is coming from previous page as a areaname

Comment: Why are you doing the same query feom `pamphletsbooking_tbl` repeatedly? Do the query once, save all the company names in an array, and then loop over that array every time you need it.

Comment: @Barmar Because in one query order by agentname and in another order by companyname is needed so only.

Comment: I'm talking about the two `SELECT DISTINCT companyname FROM pamphletsbooking_tbl` queries. They both order by `companyname`.

Comment: @Barmar i have removed the second query and kept the first query. Thanx then how to take the value from the repeated textbox.

Comment: I don't understand the question. The textboxes have named like `vendor1`, `vendor2`, etc. So you should be able to get them from `$_POST['vendor1']`, `$_POST['vendor2']`, and so on. It might be better if you just used `name="vendor[]"`, then you can access `$_POST['vendor']` as an array, and loop through all of them.

Comment: @Barmar Its simple iam displaying in a table format...1st column iam displaying agentname, 2nd column iam displaying total indent and in 1st row iam displaying companyname apart from this iam displaying textbox everywhere...... now i just want to insert the data through the textbox store it to respective agentname in the database

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6141458/make-multiple-inputs-in-mysql-table-at-once-with-one-submit-button for an example. There are many other similar questions about inserting multiple rows into the database.

Comment: @Barmar Thank you for the suggestions...

Comment: i have attached the output how to fetch the dynamic text box values and put it according to the agent name and the company name as well.....?